# I am having a problem in Xcode. It gives me "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? { <-- THE "as!" IN THIS LINE
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                
                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I tried to rewrite the code but that didn't help.

Comment: You conditionally force unwrap an optional to an optional which makes no sense and even causes the crash. Replace `as! SKView?` with `as? SKView` which evaluates to `false` if the view is not an `SKView`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView?
```

with:

```
if let view = self.view as? SKView
```

The exclamation mark is an *unsafe* unwrap – if `self.view` is not an SKView then it will crash.

But as you are unwrapping via the if statement anyway, just use the safe unwrap of the question mark. If `self.view` is not an SKView then the code in the if block won't be executed.

Comment: Most likely this answer will then lead to the question: "why isn't my view an SKView?". The OP appears to be using Sprite Kit and expects the main view to be a Sprite Kit view. This answer doesn't solve the real issue.

Comment: @HangarRash So let that question be asked. This question was "why is my code crashing?", and this is an answer to that.